# Python custom ordered data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, comparison, strict-weak-ordering

I am wondering if in Python exists a data structure for which is possible induce a custom internal ordering policy. I am aware of `OrderedDict` and whatnot, but they do not provide explicity what I am asking for. For example, `OrderedDict` just guarantees insertion order.
I really would like something that in C++ is provided with the use of comparison object: for example in `std::set<Type,Compare,Allocator>`, `Compare` is a parameter that define the internal ordering of the data structure. Usually, or probably always, it is a binary predicate that is evaluate for a pair of elements beloning to the data structure.
Is there something similar in Python? Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

[`SortedSet`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) & Co support a `key`:

```
>>> SortedSet([-3, 1, 4, 1], key=abs)
SortedSet([1, -3, 4], key=<built-in function abs>)
```

Comment: Since the OP appears to be more familiar with C++'s compare objects, it's worth adding a word to explain the difference between a custom *key* and a custom *compare*, and pointing to function [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) which transforms the latter into the former.